# How to extract photos from iPhone backup files

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I used iTunes to back up an iPhone. Now I want to get all the photos that were on the phone when it was backed up. Is there a way to do this without restoring the backup to a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, but all solutions are specific software products, which we are not allowed to recommend according to the rules of this site. Thus, I recommend that you Google “How to extract files from an iTunes backup” and you will find what you want. Some caveats, though, you should be aware of:
1. Apple has protected a lot of personal data folders in Mojave, preventing many applications from accessing certain folders. Thus, you should pay attention to what macOS you are using and the compatibility of the software you want to use.
2. You need also to check whether the software can extract a backup from iCloud if you need that. Some of them cannot do that, including the most used free option.

Comment: I thought that all third-party software can access default iTunes backup location to load the backup? Or you've added information about Mojave just in case? To @mrog - you can go to ~/Library/*user*/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup folder and just copy&paste the backup to your desktop if there will be any issues with permissions. Backups are folders with 40 random chars in name (device UDID, unique for each device).

Comment: Good call, @Minorite, that should take care of any acessibility issues.

Comment: Concerning a list of folders that are now protected from prowling software are listed here: https://carlashley.com/2018/09/28/tcc-round-up/